# SEO for a website with 2 domains

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I am redesigning a website for a company which is about to become 2 different companies. They are about to have another company which is similar.

They only want to maintain SEO for a single website and have 2 different companies' domains point to the single website, with the 2 domains benefiting from the same SEO, however to also not be confusing for visitors as both companies' domain point to the same website.

What will be the best way around this?

Comment: I am confused by this. If you mean one website with two domain names, only one will rank. The other will simply be a duplicate. Adding domain names do nothing for a site regardless of the reason for doing it. If that is what is intended, then there really is no solution for you. If I do not understand stand your question, then please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, some planning is required.

Considering following points:

- One Functional website
- Secondary domain will send traffic to the primary domain where SEO is done.
- Making sure user doesn't get confused

You may solve in following way:

Let's say you got primary domain as example.com and secondary domain as exaple1.com.

You may like to create a page about secondary domain on a primary domain like: example.com/about-example1 and set 301 redirect: secondary domain to page on primary domain about the secondary domain.
example1.com => example.com/about-example1

In this way, users will not get confused.

You can continue to do SEO on the primary domain and there will be no impact on secondary domain.

Note: You may redirect to the home page of the primary domain but users may get confused but from SEO side there will be no impact.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, want to add that they would also want both domains to benefit from the SEO, would that happen?

Comment: As soon as you say you need ranking for 2 domains, you need to have 2 different sites. Also, recommended approach would be to do SEO from zero for the secondary site and mixing is not recommended.